# What security concerns can occur if I share APNS certificate and key with others?

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I have an app that uses APNS and a server that uses SSL certificates generated by Apple member portal.

Both the app and the server are open source, and people using this solution install the server and the app in their own machines. There is no "central" server.

For others to use push notifications, they need SSL certificates that I have. What are the security implications if I share my SSL certificates (private and public) for APNS push with others?

Comment: It is mostly a reputation problem, if somebody abuses the certificate you and all others will get locked. Besides I think it is against apple terms and conditions.

Comment: Thank you. It's best I avoid it then.